# How do i create functionality for allowing website users to add a page to my website?

Tags: php, dynamic-content

So for example wikipedia, yahoo answers, or even stack overflow.

I'm trying to create a site that will allow users to create new pages of content to add to my site for other users to view.

I'm reading an introductory book on php/mysql. All i really want to know is will i find what i need in there? Is PHP what i would use to achieve that? Or do i need to use something else?

Also any general suggestions pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, PHP and MySQL is what you would need, since you are creating dynamic pages. You would use PHP to process the HTML form submits of pages, and use MySQL to store the data. You would then use PHP to list all of the pages that users have made.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just download [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download) for your site?